# Please provide me some resource to understand Horspool string searching algorithm

Tags: algorithm, pattern-matching

Please provide me some resource to understand Horspool string searching algorithm.

Please describe the construction process of the matching table and the main algorithm in a  naive way.

I have already browsed through 29 pages in the Google Search to find a good explanation, but failed.

Comment: The Wikipedia article on Boyer-Moore (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyer%E2%80%93Moore_string_search_algorithm) includes an explanation of Horspool's. Which parts of that explanation do you find unclear?

Answer (score 1):

Horspool's algorithm is a simplification of the Boyer-Moore algorithm. Once you understand the latter, understanding the former is trivial.

I think the Wikipedia page does a fairly good job explaining both: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyer%E2%80%93Moore_string_search_algorithm

Additionally, the original paper by Horspool can be downloaded here: http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.63.3421&rep=rep1&type=pdf